# What is the command to manually switch to "Hints" mode in vimperator ?

Tags: javascript, vimperator

I am looking for way to automatically switch to "Hints" mode in vimperator on page load without having to press "f".

in .vimperatorrc

```
autocmd PageLoad  .*  js <what goes here ? >
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
hints.show("o")
```

is what the key f calls per default, so you would want to use

```
autocmd PageLoad  .*  js hints.show("o")
```

Comment: I haven't found any such documentation. I found above information in the source code, in the file common/content/hints.js in the vimperator-labs repo. In the same folder, there are other files with default keymappings, with the function "mappings.add" being used.

Comment: Thank you, I see it in the source now.

Answer (score 1):

Another option for a case like this (if you don't want to consult the source to find the JS), is to use the `:normal` command, which executes the normal-mode command corresponding to the given key sequence.

```
autocmd PageLoad  .* normal f
```